# Rails Dreamhost SQL server VPS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, dreamhost

I have followed the following tutorial: http://wiki.dreamhost.com/RVM. Now if i follow it like with SQLite3 it works great. Although if I try to change to mysql database by placing in the gem file

```
gem "mysql2"
```

And then installing a database.yml in database such has follow

```
production:
 adapter: mysql2  
 encoding: utf8  
 host: localhost
 database: test-mysql2_production  
 pool: 5  
 username: test_user
 password:  
 socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
```

The reason i added database.yml on the vps is because it doesn't create one. I still find my self having problem because i try to create the command rake db:create and i get the following error

Could not find database no user found with password. Is there something i am missing? or because it is a live server, i should not do it that way and create my project a different way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you created a mysql database on dreamhost from their cpanel?

then you need a user that has access to the database.

before trying to connect to it from rails, try connecting to the mysql db directly from the command line to make sure that it's working. this should help: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-access-mysql-server-from-the-shell-prompt-command-line/

and yes, unlike heroku that creates one for you, you need a copy of database.yml